# Boolean attribute with details if YES?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In my table "Phones", I have a Boolean column 'memoryCard'.

If a phone doesn't admits an external memory card, so memoryCard = False, otherwise it is True.

But if memoryCard = True, so I have to put in my Database the Type of Memory Card.

How to model this ? should I create another column "memoryCardType" in the table "Phones" ? or I have to create a separate table that contains card mermory Types ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have a separate table for memory cards.  And you table for phones should have a foreign key reference to this table, with a column called something like `MemoryCardId`.

Next, you have a choice.  You will have a field `MemoryCardId` that can be `NULL`.  You can treat a `NULL` value as not having a memory card at all.  If so, you can put a view on phones to get the boolean value:

```
create v_phones as
    select p.*, (MemoryCardId is not null) as HasMemoryCard
    from phones;
```

Otherwise, you can have a separate flag (as you are suggesting in the question).  You would only use `MemoryCardId` when the value of the flag is true.  In most databases, you could add a `check` constraint to ensure that the id and flag are aligned.  Alas, in MySQL, you would need to do this with a trigger instead.

EDIT:

The advantage of an explicit table over an `enum`:

- You are not constrained to arbitrary limits on the number of values in the enum (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html#enum-limits)).
- If the memory card names are actually numbers, the parse won't get confused.
- You can store additional information about the memory card -- the manufacturer, date of release, color of packaging, if you like.
- The solution is more portable to other databases.

Comment: *"you should have a separate table for memory cards"* What's the advantage of this vs. an `ENUM` column? The only one I can think of, is that a separate table is end-user-editable, but that is *probably* not applicable in this case.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker . . . See my edited answer.  The list is too long to put into a comment.

Comment: I prefer to create a separate table for memory card types, but I have a question : If MemoryCardId = Null then we have two cases : 1-The phonee doesn't admit an external memory card 2- We don't have this information (I don't have yet if It admits or Not)

Comment: @ista9im . . . Exactly.  In that case, you want a separate boolean value, and not to depend the id.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ... So, how to make this ? do I have to create a boolean column InformationExist (in table "Phones") in addition to foreign key "MemoryCardId" ?

Comment: @ista9im . . . You want a flag, say `HasMemoryCard` along with the foreign key reference `MemoryCardid`.